# How to convert data to pdf files and then insert to zip and download it

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I got from the database binary data that it is actually PDF file

```
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

This reader needs to be read 3 times, because I have 3 pdf files.

```
while (reader.Read() && !reader.IsDBNull(1))
{
   byte[] BytesData = (byte[])reader["PDF_DATA"];
}
```

How do I convert the binary data to pdf, and then insert all the files to a ZIP file, and then download it?

Comment: When you say 'download', what sort of application is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bytes in your database were taken from a PDF file, then they are already in the correct format and don't need any conversion.

You need a ZIP library, something like SharpZipLib, then you can add each file to it as a Stream.

Using SharpZipLib, you could amend your DB read method like so:

```
        var i = 0;
        using (var zipFile = new ZipFile(""))
        {
            var factory = new ZipEntryFactory();

            while (reader.Read() && !reader.IsDBNull(1))
            {
                byte[] BytesData = (byte[])reader["PDF_DATA"];
                zipFile.Add(new DbFileSource(BytesData), "file-" + i);
                i++;
            }
        }
```

You will also need to make a basic data source class to make the above code work:

```
    public class DbFileSource : IStaticDataSource
    {
        public DbFileSource(byte[] bytes)
        {
            _bytes = bytes;
        }

        private readonly byte[] _bytes;

        public Stream GetSource()
        {
            return new MemoryStream(_bytes);
        }
    }
```

Caveat: I've not tried this yet, but hopefully it's a good starting point for you.